# How to allow the user to enter a string and store that string into an array using a for loop in Java

Tags: java, arrays

Today as I was creating a java program for fun I came across an error. The program I am making asks the user to enter 5 family names and assigns those names into an array. I will later create the code to display the names, however, For some reason I cannot assign a string literal into a string array. To be more clear here is my code that I have written so far. In the code I will disregard the import, class, and method statements just for simplicity. I am using NetBeans IDE.

```
// Create objects and array

Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
string names[] = new string[5];

// Ask the user to enter his or her family members names
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    System.out.println("Enter a family member name: ");
    names[i] = keyboard.nextLine();
}
```

For some reason the statement `

```
names[i] = keyboard.nextLine();
```

shows the red squiggly marks.
What is the problem? Thank you.

Comment: `String` with a capital `S` for starters.

Comment: Thank you so much! That did the trick.

Comment: "*What is the problem?*" actually that is your task to show us problem you are facing. We can only help you with *why* it happens and how to fix it parts. So *what* happens when you try to use your code? Do you get any errors/exceptions/incorrect results?

Comment: @Yoda:  Please don't make code edits which may well be indicative of the actual problem.  Leave that for the OP to handle.